# Can I select insert to mysql but modify values manually?

Tags: mysql

```
insert into 
 keyword_history (
   keyword_id, 
   searchengine, 
   location, 
   "4", 
   curdate()
   ) 
 select 
  keyword_id, 
  searchengine, 
  location 
 from 
  keyword_history 
 where 
  history_id = 21
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is :

1. select a row from a table
2. insert it again but this time with current date and the value "4"

Comment: do you want to insert a new one that is the same as the older one except for the date, or do you want to update the previous one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can. You may want to try the following instead:

```
INSERT INTO keyword_history 
(
   keyword_id, 
   searchengine, 
   location, 
   rec_date, 
   currentrank
) 
SELECT  keyword_id, 
        searchengine, 
        location,
        curdate(),
        '4' 
FROM    keyword_history 
WHERE   history_id = 21;
```

**EDIT:** Updated field names as per comment below.

Comment: I think you may have mixed up the column names / values.

Comment: insert into 
 keyword_history (
   keyword_id, 
   searchengine, 
   location, 
   rec_date,
   currentrank
   ) 
 select 
  keyword_id, 
  searchengine, 
  location,
   curdate(), '4'
    
 from 
  keyword_history 
 where 
  history_id = 21

Answer (score 1):

Try this; it seems you're putting values in your field list inadvertently...

```
insert into keyword_history 
  (keyword_id, searchengine, location, your_number_col, your_date_col) 
select keyword_id, searchengine, location, '4', curdate()
from keyword_history 
where history_id = 21
```